# Exception Localizing MenuStrip Control

Tags: c#, resources, menustrip

I have a MenuStrip control with all translations entered for several languages. When I try to change the culture dynamically all controls are changing the language as it must be except the MenuStrip. Here is the code which I used specifically for MenuStrip:

```
    protected ComponentResourceManager res2;

    private void signOutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoginForm login = new LoginForm();
        if (login.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //this is for other controls
            resManager = new ComponentResourceManager(this.GetType());
            this.ApplyResources(this, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);

            //this is for MenuStrip
            res2 = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(MenuStrip));
            this.ApplyResourcesToolStripMenuItem(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
        }

    }

    private void ApplyResourcesToolStripMenuItem(CultureInfo lang)
    {
        foreach (ToolStripItem m in this.menuStrip1.Items)
        {
            //resources.ApplyResources(m, m.Name, lang);
            if (m is ToolStripMenuItem)
            {
                string text = res2.GetString(m.Name + ".Text", lang); //Exception is thrown here
                if (text != null)
                    m.Text = text;
            }
        }
    }
```

I used another developer's code sample from this forum and made minor changes.
Now when I change culture at runtime, I get the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not find any resources appropriate for
>   the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure
>   "System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip.resources" was correctly embedded or
>   linked into assembly "System.Windows.Forms" at compile time, or that
>   all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

I have checked the resource file and all MenuStripItems have all translations/values there...

I failed to find solution in the internet, so would highly appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wonder why you're doing _localization_ manually, isn't designer generated code? BTW culture for user interface is CurrentUICulture, not CurrentCulture.

Comment: Adriano, thank you for the comment. The point is that this is my first experience with localization and what I did is that I set translations for every language in design time, but on clicking a button it should change based on selected values. I could not find another solution...

Comment: Localization is not just strings, you should set Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture (not Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture) to new culture and then **reload** Form. Yes, you may _assume_ WinForms controls won't cache anything and you may ignore shortcuts, images, layouts, orientation and so on but it's a big big (and broken) assumption.

Comment: Thanks, Adriano... I wonder how easy solutions can be sometimes! I was looking for harder solution while there was the easiest one! I will post the solution in 'reply'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So since I'm a beginner in localizing, the solution is much more easier than one that I have posted. Maybe this can help for other beginners too.

So I removed all my code which actually was a bulk of headache and replaced it with the following code:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(StaticValues.currentCulture);
this.Controls.Clear();
this.InitializeComponent();
```

And it worked easily. And yes, thanks to Adriano Repetti!

Comment: Just a note: form _should_ be disposed and recreated. Calling InitializeComponents() twice may introduce many _weird_ bugs (for example event handlers on Form called twice). Moreover in more complex scenarios (where you keep _references_ to controls in your class fields) code will be simply broken (imagine a cache of ListViewItem when using ListView in virtual mode, just for example).

Comment: so how can I reload the form then? Because as I have noted, the form needs to be reloaded once CurrentUICulture is changed.

Comment: That's the tricky part, it has to be done outside the form and it's not easy (unless in very simple scenarios) because every open form has to be properly initialized, opened in right order and so on. If it's not an issue and you save that setting it's easier to restart entire application...

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the recommendation! Then I'll go on with restart.